# DLIB - Is it possible to retrain a trained Neural Network

Tags: dlib

I have 2 questions:

1. I am using svr_trainer, and I have got some dataset to train the model. But I want to re-train the model with more dataset later. Is it possible to do this ? Or I need to train with old and new dataset again ?
2. Is there a way to know how long the training will take for svr_trainer ?
   I didnot find any function like be_verbose() implemented for svr_trainer.

I am relatively new to dlib. I am sorry if my questions sound dumb.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't retrain like that.  You have to give the whole dataset during training.  At least if you used that tool.  It's possible to use the underlying optimizers in dlib to construct all kinds of incremental training methods, but I wouldn't recommend trying that sort of thing unless you are certain you really understand what you are trying to accomplish.

There isn't a straight forward way to know how long training is going to take unfortunately.